# Unity 4.6 New GUI Issue with GIT

Tags: unity

I am using Unity 4.6 new UI. I have my project setup on bit bucket (using GIT). It was working fine but when I cloned the project on another macbook. All the unity new UI scripts went missing. Is there any workaround for this issue ?

I am using same unity version on both macbooks. Editor Settings screenshot attached 
[image]

Ref of inspector where scripts went missing.
[Editor Settings[image: ][1]]

Comment: Did you add the meta files to your git repo?

Comment: My issue was solved by deleting library folder

Reference : http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-4-6-ui-issue-with-git.296847/#post-1955505